# State management when using redux-form wizard form

Tags: redux-form

I'm about to implement a wizard form using [redux-form's wizard form](http://redux-form.com/5.3.1/#/examples/wizard?_k=7vtrpw) and I noticed that they recommend using `this.setState()` when moving between pages (shown below). Doesn't this go against redux practices? I was wondering if someone has had troubles linking this up to the store and feels that you'd be better off dispatching actions to control the page navigation.

```
class WizardForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.nextPage = this.nextPage.bind(this)
    this.previousPage = this.previousPage.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      page: 1
    }
  }

  nextPage() {
    this.setState({ page: this.state.page + 1 })
  }

  previousPage() {
    this.setState({ page: this.state.page - 1 })
  }

  render() {
    const { onSubmit } = this.props
    const { page } = this.state
    return (<div>
        {page === 1 && <WizardFormFirstPage onSubmit={this.nextPage}/>}
        {page === 2 && <WizardFormSecondPage previousPage={this.previousPage} onSubmit={this.nextPage}/>}
        {page === 3 && <WizardFormThirdPage previousPage={this.previousPage} onSubmit={onSubmit}/>}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The use of `setState` in the wizard example is meant to be illustrative, not prescriptive. I personally use `nextPage` and `previousPage` to dispatch actions that increment/decrement page index, as well as manage page history.